# What is the proper way to export tabular data in excel format in java web applications?

Tags: java, jqgrid, export-to-excel, displaytag

Display tag has the feature to export tyable data in excel or pdf. JQgrid is also used for listing purposes. But I am not sure if it supports exporting.

So, what is the most feasable way to export large data in excel or pdf in java based web applications?

Are there any other tools available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel you can just export a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file - but there's also [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) which you could use. For PDF there's [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) but be aware that the (free) [licence for iText](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php) is very restrictive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But using POI or itext, I will have to write code to export manually.The one advantage display tag has, is that it gives in built export option. I was thinking if there is anything else available in the same line as display tag?